# how to change the color of the snackbar in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using snackBar, to display a message when someone logs out. The following is the code, I am trying to change the color of panel from dark grey into another color, I found this solution:

> panelClass: ['danger']

which is suppose to change the color of the panel into red (danger), but this doesnt work:

```
  message: string = 'You Have Logged out.';
  open() {
    this.snackBar.open(this.message, '', {
      duration: 2000,
      panelClass: ['danger'],
   });
  }
```

how can I change the panel color into  something else?

Comment: What framework are you using? Ionic?

Comment: @nachshonf angular + typescript

Comment: Do you set the background color in the danger class?

Comment: @JosefKatič yes, but I have kind make it work, i am not sure if its the best solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using @angular:

### 1 - Create a global CSS class

```css
.custom-css-class {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

If you don't wanna create a global style, set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on the component decorator where you're want to use the snackbar with the custom background color (in the end it'll be placed on the global scope):

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class SagaSnackbarComponent {
```

### 2 - Call the snackbar service passing the class on configs

```
constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

...

this._snackBar.open(message, action, {
      panelClass: 'custom-css-class'
    });
```

Here you can see it working in a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcjchx?file=app/snack-bar-overview-example.css).

Comment: so I need to make snackbar into a seprate component?

Comment: No. The CSS class must be global, by declaring it on styles.css, or by setting your component's encapsulation to None.

Comment: Yes, I did. Take a look on the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcjchx?file=app/snack-bar-overview-example.css

Comment: @jpavel so I added encapsulation  to my root component and in my rootcomponent class I made a function that gets a custom css, now the color is changed is this a good way to avoid making the snackbar component?

Comment: What encapsulation does is allowing your component's style to be global. Nothing else. What you must consider when deciding to build a separate component to be loaded inside the `snackbar`, is the complexity of what you wanna show on it. Complex views deserve their own component.

Comment: I see my errr now the style is gone!

Comment: Thanks Juliano, great answer :-)